# Why doesn't the `rmdir /s /q` command delete the folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following folder structure

```
root
|-- _keep (not existing only the script creates it) 
|
|-- common
|   |-- util
|   |   |-- util.js
|   |
|   |-- data
|       |-- data.js
|
|-- custom_prefix_folder_1
|   |-- subfolder_1
|   |   |-- file1.js
|   |
|   |-- subfolder_2
|   |   |-- file2.js
|   |
|   |-- main.js
|
|-- custom_prefix_folder_2
    |-- subfolder_3
    |   |-- file3.js
    |
    |-- subfolder_4
    |   |-- file4.js
    |
    |-- main.js
```

I want to do the following:

- Create the `_keep` folder if it doesn't exist or make it empty it it exists
- Iterate through all the folders matching the `custom_prefix_*` regex

  - Copy all of the `current` folder's contents (files and folders) to the `_keep` folder
  - Copy all of the `common` folder's content to the `current` folder
  - Execute the `clasp push` command
  - Delete all of the `current` folder's content
  - Copy all the content from the `_keep` folder
  - Make the `_keep` folder empty
- Delete the `_keep` folder

I have the following script which does it for me in a weird way

```
@echo off

set commonFolder=.\common

set keepFolder=.\_keep

if exist %keepFolder% rmdir /s /q %keepFolder%
if not exist %keepFolder% mkdir %keepFolder%
del /s /q %keepFolder% >nul

for /d %%f in (custom_prefix_*) do (
    echo Processing folder %%f...

    xcopy /s /e /y %%f %keepFolder% >nul
    xcopy /s /e /y %commonFolder% %%f >nul

    cd %%f
    clasp push

    del /s /q * >nul
    for /d %%s in (*) do (
        rmdir /s /q %%s
    )

    cd ..

    xcopy /s /e /y %keepFolder% %%f >nul

    del /s /q %keepFolder% >nul

    rem DELETION INSIDE CYCLE
    rmdir /s /q %keepFolder%

    echo === Done processing folder %%f ===
)

echo All done.
```

As you see the deletion of the `_keep` folder is inside the cycle while it could be outside. If I move it outside the cycle (like described below) when the script ends there is the `_keep` folder with some empty subfolders (remaining from the custom_prefix_* folders)

```
@echo off

set commonFolder=.\common

set keepFolder=.\_keep

if exist %keepFolder% rmdir /s /q %keepFolder%
if not exist %keepFolder% mkdir %keepFolder%
del /s /q %keepFolder% >nul

for /d %%f in (custom_prefix_*) do (
    echo Processing folder %%f...

    xcopy /s /e /y %%f %keepFolder% >nul
    xcopy /s /e /y %commonFolder% %%f >nul

    cd %%f
    clasp push

    del /s /q * >nul
    for /d %%s in (*) do (
        rmdir /s /q %%s
    )

    cd ..

    xcopy /s /e /y %keepFolder% %%f >nul

    del /s /q %keepFolder% >nul

    echo === Done processing folder %%f ===
)

rem DELETION INSIDE CYCLE
rmdir /s /q %keepFolder%

echo All done.
```

What am I missing? Why can't I move the deletion outside the cycle?

Additional info: I don't really think it matters but I'm running this file through a Make command, see the makefile below

```
default: help

pushall: ## Run the clasp_push_all.bat file
    cmd.exe /c clasp_push_all.bat

help: ## This help message
    @fgrep -h "##" $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | fgrep -v fgrep | sed -e 's/\\$$//' -e 's/:.*#/: #/' | column -t -s '##'
```